# Мне нужно перебирать все значение profit и добавить все числа в одну переменную

Tags: python

Данные берутся request с post запроса

```
{'rows': [{'campaign': 'campaign', 'profit': 70},
{'campaign': 'campagin', 'profit': 250},
{'campaign': 'campaign', 'profit': 35},
{'campaign': 'campaign', 'profit': 70},
```

Нужно перебирать все значение profit и добавить все числа в одну переменную allprofit = 435
Совсем новичок на пайтоне не пишу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это делается достаточно просто:

```
all_profit = sum([x['profit'] for x in data['rows']])
```

Чтобы разобраться в решении советую почитать документацию:
[list comprehenshion](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) и [dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries).

Comment: Лучший бро) Спасибо